# Good how-to's for accessibility in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm building a WPF app and I'm tyring to find information or a walkthrough on how to make it accessible for screen readers. I've trawled through MSDN and found some articles regarding UI Automation (UIA). Basically I found a lot of "okay, this is UIA! it's used for testing but also accessibility" but nothing along the lines of "this is how you use it in WPF".

Any input would be great. Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Very broad question. First or all, it works without doing nothing special. And, then, the next step is to override your own UIElements' OnCreateAutomationPeer() method and do fancy things. But only if the first approach (ie: doing nothing) failed. You can use UIA tools (inspect.exe for example) to check what your application exposes by default.

Comment: Microsoft have developed a tool that will allow you to interegate your application (for automation purposes) and it also has a testing facility (FastPass) that will find issues with your code/markup - https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/windows/overview/